# When I click on toggle button, new content does not effect to jaqury scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar, toggle

If you look at below site
http://w4b.com.au/toggle/

and click one of question bar, it will display answer
but blue scroll bar are stayed same.

Used jquery code for this

---

```
<script src="javascript/jquery.custom-scrollbar.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
        $(".genworth").customScrollbar();

    });
</script> 



<!--JQUERY TOGGLE -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $('.toggle1').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
    $('#toggle2').click(function() {
        $('.toggle2').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
    $('#toggle3').click(function() {
        $('.toggle3').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
    $('#toggle4').click(function() {
        $('.toggle4').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
    $('#toggle5').click(function() {
        $('.toggle5').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
    $('#toggle6').click(function() {
        $('.toggle6').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
    $('#toggle7').click(function() {
        $('.toggle7').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
    $('#toggle8').click(function() {
        $('.toggle8').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
    $('#toggle9').click(function() {
        $('.toggle9').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });
    $('#toggle10').click(function() {
        $('.toggle10').slideToggle('fast');

        return false;
    });

</script>

<!--JQUERY TOGGLE END-->
```

---

Anyone knows how to fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: can u set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

First of all (sorry for offtop), I would simplify your jQuery to make it easier to read and way shorter. Like this:

```
$("a[id^='toggle']").click(function(){
    var toShow = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.'+ toShow).slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Also if you read the docs, your plugin has function resize() which takes care of your problem. Check it here https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar#resizekeepposition

Try adding customScrollbar("resize", true);